# SVG Filter turbulence used in css filters to apply noise but it's not transparent

Tags: html, css, svg, filter

My goal is to make my background noisy while being transparent. I have a div container in which I have the whole page, for the example I have a blue circle in this "div container". The end goal is to make the circle blurry and move it thanks to JS to animate the background, but that's later. The circle has to be visible, but obviously the texture created thanks to the SVG is in the way. I don't want to use z-index to put it in the background, since I want the noise to be applied on the circle, and opacity does not seem to be the good way to do it. Any ideas?

Here's the HTML:

```css
.background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  filter: url(#noiseFilter);
}

.circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <svg style="display: none">
    <filter id='noiseFilter'>
      <feTurbulence 
      type='fractalNoise' 
      baseFrequency='6.29' 
      numOctaves='6' 
      stitchTiles='stitch'/>
    </filter>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.background {
  background: #555;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  backdrop-filter: url(#noiseFilter);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: url(#noiseFilter)
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circle"></div>

    <svg style="display: none">
      <filter id='noiseFilter'>
        <feTurbulence 
          type='fractalNoise' 
          baseFrequency='6.29' 
          numOctaves='6' 
          stitchTiles='stitch'
        />
      </filter>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue with your code was that the filter was being applied to the circle as well. That's why it wasn't appearing.

That was fixed by using a grey background and a backdrop filter on the wrapper to separate the background from the filter. The filter will only be applied to the background in this case.

I recommend reading the documentation for [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#:%7E:text=The%20backdrop%2Dfilter%20CSS%20property,background%20at%20least%20partially%20transparent.) for more information if you want.

EDIT: added the `-webkit-backdrop-filter` attribute since Safari only supports that currently

Comment: Hello! It works as expected! Thanks a lot, the only problem is that it doesn't work on Safari, the backdrop filter seems to not be supported :/ thank you though :)

Comment: ah. forgot about that. You can use `-webkit-backdrop-filter` for Safari

Answer (score 0):

I have also found success by using just filter: url(#noise); while writing the CSS instead of backdrop-filter.

I know not entirely kosher, but try it and see if it works.

I also have code that won't work without the word backdrop, so I alternate between using both to see which works best.

```
.noise {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    filter: url(#noise);
    height: 22.5vh;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .6;
    bottom: 1.7vh;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).